How to assign appropriate ZipCode from one table to geographical data from anothr table in PySpark / Python?
I have in PySpark:
Input data:

table location_df with columns:


location (values: Canada, Costa Rica, Mexico, Puerto Rico, United States)

answer_label
(values: ['Guadalajara',
'San José',
'Heredia',
'Puntarenas',
'Do not wish to answer',
'Cartago',
'Alajuela',
'Limon',
'Guanacaste',
'Monterrey',
'MidWest',
'Arizona',
'Alaska',
'NorthEast',
'Arkansas',
'Alabama',
'South',
'West',
'Northeast',
'Maryland',
'Michigan',
'Mississippi',
'Maine',
'Kentucky',
'Minnesota',
'Massachusetts',
'Louisiana',
'Iowa',
'Kansas',
'Ohio',
'Rhode Island',
'South Carolina',
'Vermont',
'West Virginia',
'Wisconsin',
'Pennsylvania',
'Washington',
'Washington DC',
'South Dakota',
'Oklahoma',
'Utah',
'Virginia',
'Texas',
'Wyoming',
'Tennessee',
'Oregon',
'Alberta',
'British Colombia',
'Ontario',
'New Brunswick',
'Manitoba',
'Prince Edward Island',
'Quebec',
'Nova Scotia',
'Saskatchewan',
'Newfoundland and Labrador',
'Mayagüez',
'Midwest',
'San Juan Metro',
'Caguas',
'San Juan Sub',
'Otras',
'México D.F.',
'Ponce',
'Arecibo',
'Hawaii',
'Florida',
'California',
'Connecticut',
'Georgia',
'Idaho',
'Illinois',
'Indiana',
'Colorado',
'Delaware',
'Nevada',
'North Carolina',
'Nebraska',
'New York',
'Montana',
'New Mexico',
'North Dakota',
'Missouri',
'New Hampshire',
'New Jersey']



table imp_df with column ZipCode with example values: '68364', '30133' and many many more...

My question:
How to create pipeline to merge above datasets (location_df and imp_df) based on values in column "answer_label" from location_df and assign to them appropriate ZipCode from column "ZipCode" from table "imp_df" ?
Desired output
As an output I need all columns from table "location_df" and assigned to each value from the "answer_label" column the corresponding ZipCode from the ZipCode column of the imp_df table. Like below:
location | answer_label | ZipCode 

Of course, if more than 1 ZipCode matches a given geographic land, then such a line should be duplicated as many times as there are postal codes assigned to a given geographic land.
Is there any package in python or PySpark to assign this according to actual geographical data ? Request for an example code :)

Are there any other columns in imp_df? or does it only have one ZipCode column?

Yes, in imp_df there is many more other columns columns

Any common column between imp_df and location_df to be used to join them? otherwise, it is impossible to map these ZipCodes to locations, unless extracting it from external sources which wouldn't really be the mapping to imp_df

There is no column by which these tables could be connected, the very essence of this task is to connect these tables by region name and postal code using some python libraries that contain geolocation data.

You can use Google API or Nominatim API to get ZipCodes of a given location. But this doesn't ensure that the returned ZipCodes are present in the imp_df. In other words, if you are ok to use external resources this means that you should ignore the imp_df. Here's how you can do it with Nominatim https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-zip-code-with-given-location-using-geopy-in-python/

Do you have some example code for my example data from my quesiton ?

yes I will post an answer

As you mentioned, joining imp_df and location_df is not possible since there are no common fields. In this case, you should use external sources like: Nominatim(You can only make a limited number of calls for free, see here) or any other geolocation package.
An implementation using Nominatim can be like below,it is also required that you install geopy and also make sure
:
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, explode, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim



def get_zip_codes(location):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="your-geopy-api-agent")
    try:
        loc = geolocator.geocode(location)
        if loc:
            loc_data = loc.raw['display_name'].split()
            zip_code = loc_data[-2] if len(loc_data) >= 2 else None
            return [zip_code] if zip_code else []
    except:
        return []

# Step 1: Filter out rows with `answer_label="Do not wish to answer"`
filtered_df = location_df.filter(location_df.answer_label != "Do not wish to answer")

# Register the UDF
get_zip_codes_udf = udf(get_zip_codes, ArrayType(StringType()))

# Step 2: Apply the UDF to get the list of zip codes
zip_codes_df = filtered_df.withColumn("zip_codes", get_zip_codes_udf(filtered_df.answer_label))

# Step 3: Explode the zip_codes column
exploded_df = zip_codes_df.withColumn("zip_code", explode("zip_codes")).drop("zip_codes")

# Step 4: Join with the imp_df DataFrame (only if you want to validate the zipcodes with `imp_df`)
final_df = exploded_df.join(imp_df, exploded_df.zip_code == imp_df.ZipCode, "left") \
                      .select(exploded_df.location, exploded_df.answer_label, imp_df.ZipCode)

First, the rows that don't contain a location are filtered out, then for each location, the ZipCodes are fetched via API calls to Nominatim and lastly, the df is exploded to make sure if one location has more than one zip_code it is populated in different rows. Step 4 is optional for when you are requried to validate the data with imp_df or for case that you only have to consider the zip_codes in imp_df

for more info on Nominatim, see here: https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/library/Getting-Started/

Parman M. Alizadeh - what is your-geopy-api-agent ? where to get it from ?

it's a string that identifies the application or user that is making requests to the Nominatim geocoding service. It is a requirement set by the Nominatim service to help them track and manage the usage of their service. You can include a valid email address
